# Java design (using final field in functions)

Tags: java

I've programmed in Java for a year and took a break to do some python for the last year. I'm back to java and I'm confused with some design stuff.

Say I have a class that does almost everything static

```
public class Example{

      String list = {{"A", "apple"}, {"B","banana"}, {"C", "can"}}

    public static manipulateTheList(){

        // do something with the above list

    }

    public static anotherManipulateTheList(){

        // do something with the above list

    }
}
```

And it won't let me use `this.list` because the method is static. But I don't think I should be defining the list in the method every time since all the methods in the class will use the same list.

Is there a solution for this and what would be the best practice for this kind of situation..?

Comment: Is the list supposed to be a constant or vary with each instance of the class?

Comment: If the list is always the same, perhaps it should be static and your methods do not need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the list as a `static` member, and if you don't intend to reassign it, also declare it as `final`:

```
private static final String LIST = {{"A", "apple"}, {"B", "banana"}, {"C", "can"}};
```

You can refer to the list inside instance and static methods, like this:

```
Example.LIST
```

Be aware that *any* instance or static method will be able to access it... and if you modify it, the change will be reflected everywhere. That's what makes `static` members so dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You only can use static global variables in static methods, but you can use a static variable in a instance method. Confused? Well, the word **static** is used for declare a object pointing to a determined place in the memory, so you can access to this value from any class (and this depends of the access modifier public, private, protected, default). Static methods often are called class methods, because they can be invoked directly without an instance of the class.

If you add the **final** modifier it will be a constant, and the convention to name this is with all letters in upper case, maybe something like:

```
public static final String[][] LIST = {{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
//can be named LIST_LETTERS too
```

The final modifier indicates that this value will never change.

I think you can declare your method as static if you gonna use this on a Util class, so your String array can be anything you want to put as parameter and your method will be the always the same.

You can find more information about static modifier [here](https://coderanch.com/t/448534/java/java/static-modifier)

i hope it can help you.